# Cannot call std::invoke() with auto& parameter via std::ref()

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++17

I am trying to create a `Invoker` object which stores both a functor and a set of parameters for this functor - all by value (used for threading).
`Invoker::operator()()` will call the stored functor with the copied parameters.

Everything is working fine so far, until one tries to pass a parameter by `auto&` using `std::ref(variable)`. Specifically this code should work, but instead it does not compile with the given error message:

```
int var = 0;
Invoker{
    [](auto& r) {
        printf("%d\n", r);
    }, std::ref(var)
}();
```

I expect it to work similar to how `std::thread` works with this example.
The error message is:

> ```
> test.cpp:65:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘invoke(std::__tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<main()::<lambda(auto:1&)>, std::reference_wrapper<int> > >, std::__tuple_element_t<1, std::tuple<main()::<lambda(auto:1&)>, std::reference_wrapper<int> > >)’
>    std::invoke(std::get<Indicies>(std::move(args))...);
>    ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

My current `Invoker` class:

```
template<typename... Args>
struct Invoker {
    std::tuple<std::decay_t<Args>...> args;

    explicit Invoker(Args... args)
        : args(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    { }

    template<size_t... Indices>
    void _Invoke(std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
        std::invoke(std::get<Indices>(std::move(args))...);
    }

    void operator()() {
        _Invoke(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<decltype(args)>>{});
    }
};

/* Invoker deduction guide (perfectly forward any parameters with full type!) */
template<typename Function, typename... Args>
Invoker(Function&&, Args&&...) -> Invoker<Function&&, Args&&...>;
```

[See here](https://wandbox.org/nojs/gcc-head/permlink/ceABK8PiWxMxeO18) for an online version of this problem. The error message suggests, that the deduced type of `auto&` is `std::reference_wrapper<int>&`, when it should be `int&`. Unfortunately I cannot come up with a solution to this problem.

#### EDIT:

As the comments showed, the expression

```
int var = 5;
std::thread{ [](auto& r) { printf("%d\n", r); }, std::ref(var) };
```

only compiles with `gcc >= 7.1.0`. I'd appreciate to see elaboration on this topic, especially if this is correct behavior by the c++ standard.

Comment: Deduction for `auto` uses the same rules for template argument deduction, which doesn't allow for implicit conversions. The problem can be reproduced with `int n = 5; auto& r = ref(n);`. Since `ref(n)` is an rvalue it can't bind to the lvalue reference.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Nevertheless it is working as expected when using `std::thread`. I want to replicate that behaviour

Comment: @nyronium No, `std::thread([] (auto &ref) {}, std::ref(var));` never compiles.

Comment: @liliscent You are wrong. See [proof](https://wandbox.org/nojs/gcc-head/permlink/giFCa2CzBHFUNFI9).

Comment: @nyronium You are wrong, this code should not compile. https://wandbox.org/permlink/GvftBTador5f1iuN

Comment: @liliscent It works with `gcc 7.1.0` and upwards. Can you cite the standard where it says this behavior is not correct?

Comment: @nyronium [thread.thread.constr/5](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/thread.thread.constr#5). gcc's behavior is contradictory to itself.

Comment: Reported as https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84532

Answer (score 5):

`INVOKE` does not generally unwrap `reference_wrapper` arguments; they are used as-is (with one exception not relevant here: if you invoke a pointer to member  with a `reference_wrapper` as the first argument, that argument is unwrapped). Therefore, `invoke([](auto&){}, std::ref(var));` will attempt to invoke the lambda with an rvalue `reference_wrapper`, which is ill-formed for attempting to bind an rvalue to an lvalue reference.

The observed behavior with `std::thread` is a [libstdc++ bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84532) that has been fixed. Briefly, libstdc++'s `std::thread` stores the provided arguments in a `tuple`, which was (incorrectly) constructed with `make_tuple` (which unwraps `reference_wrapper`s).